# Add exception to htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following htaccess rewrite to rewrite my urls from something like:

> http://mysite.tdl/about

to

> http://mysite.tdl?index.php?cl=about

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)$ /index.php?cl=$1
```

This is working so for - however I have some folders which I actually want to access - therefore I'd like to **not** redirect calls going to something like http://mysite.tdl/out/... Is there a possibility to add some (not only one) path exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
#skip the rule if the request is for a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)$ /index.php?cl=$1
```